# Append dict items to a list with a single line for loop

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, dictionary-comprehension

I have a list

```
lst = []
```

I have dict entries

```
a= {'a':1,'b':2}
```

I wish to write a for loop in a comprehension manner filling the list. 
What I have tried is

```
lst.append(k,v) for (k,v) in a.items()
```

I need to then update the dict as

```
a = {'c':3, 'd':4}
```

Then again update the list `lst`.

Which adds the tuples as `[('a',1)('b',2)('c',3)('d',4)]`
What is the right way to iterate through a dict and fill the list?

Comment: What do you want the list to be filled up with ? `keys`, `values` or both ?

Comment: Both. As in this example like lst = [('a',1)('b',2)]

Comment: append will take only one arguement

Comment: Try `lst  = a.items()`

Comment: @ZdaR see the updated answer, is this what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the syntax for a list comprehension is and should do what you're looking for:

```
lst = [(k,v) for k,v in a.items()]
```

In general [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) works like this:

```
someList = [doSomething(x) for x in somethingYouCanIterate]
```

**OUTPUT**

```
>>> lst
[('a', 1), ('b', 2)]
```

**P.S.** Apart from the question asked, you can also get what you're trying to do without list comprehension by simply calling :

```
lst = a.items()
```

this will again give you a list of tuples of `(key, value)` pairs of the dictionary items.

**EDIT**

After your updated question, since you're updating the dictionary and want the key value pairs in a list, you should do it like:

```
a= {'a':1,'b':2}
oldA = a.copy()
#after performing some operation
a = {'c':3, 'd':4}
oldA.update(a)
# when all your updates on a is done
lst = oldA.items() #or [(k,v) for k,v in oldA.items()]
# or instead of updating a and maintaining a copy
# you can simply update it like : a.update({'c':3, 'd':4}) instead of a = {'c':3, 'd':4}
```

Comment: Thank you Ashish. This gives me `dict_items([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)])`. If I need to convert it to a list of tuples. What would be the procedure?

Comment: simply use `list()` for that

Answer (score 1):

One approach is:

```
a = {"a" : 1, "b" : 2}

lst = [(k, a[k]) for k in a]

a = {"c" : 3, "d" : 4}

lst += [(k, a[k]) for k in a]
```

Where the contents of `lst` are `[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3), ('d', 4)]`.

Alternatively, using the `dict` class' `.items()` function to accomplish the same:

```
a = {"a" : 1, "b" : 2}

lst = [b for b in a.items()]

a = {"c" : 3, "d" : 4}

lst += [b for b in a.items()]
```

Comment: Use a.items() instead of iterating over keys. items() will give a you tuple.

Comment: @FujiClado Nice! I just edited the answer to incorporate that.

Answer (score 1):

There are many valid ways to achieve this. The most easy route is using

```
a = {"a" : 1, "b" : 2}
lst = list(a.items())
```

Alternatives include using the `zip` function, list comprehension etc.

Comment: why your using zip()? it can be done using a.items() , it's more readable.

Comment: `zip` was intended to demonstrate alternative ways. You are, however, correct in that this reduces readability, so I updated the answer accordingly, while still mentioning the `zip` function.